# How can I choose r elements from n elements with replacement? Which one is the appropriate formula $(n) ^r$ or $C^{n+r-1}_{r}$ and why?

Tags: combinatorics

For example: Given $r$ integers, 0<r<10 are chosen from (0,1,2,.....9) at random and with replacement. Now according to me the total possible ways should be $C^{n+r-1}_{r}$  but the answer in the assignment shows $10^r$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: $C^{r}_{n+r-1}$ seems wrong to me,Speaking of which one to use , you have to know that we use combiation ($C^{n}_{r}$), when we have to select r objects among n at one time,It would also be better ffor you to explain why you thought of $C^{r}_{n+r-1}$, so that we can point out the mistake.

Comment: Since you are sampling with replacement, after having $n$ choices for the first selection, you **again** have $n$ choices for the next selection.  When sampling without replacement, you have only $(n-1)$ choices for the next selection.  $$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!} \times \frac{1}{r!}$$ actually represents the number of permutations, when sampling without replacement, coupled with an overcounting adjustment factor, to convert permutations into combinations.

Comment: A much more difficult question, which my previous comment **ducked** is what happens if you are sampling with replacement, but you regard the order that the items are selected as **not relevant**,

Comment: Exactly, for example if we have to choose 2 alphabets out of 4 say with replacement (A, B, C, D). Then the possible cases should be (AA, BB, CC, DD, AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD) (10 in count) which can be calculated using the formula n+r-1Cr but according to the other formula, they should be 16 i.e.N^r. Why we are considering the additional six cases of (BA, CA, DA, CB, DB, DC) since the order in combination doesn't matter and AB and BA are considered as the same thing.

Comment: @RamanujanXV, that was a typing mistake, I am new here, not used to it. Check now. Also, check my other comment where I am asking why we are considering 6 extra cases.

Comment: @8103JitenderBishnoi We are considering the 6 extra cases because we are not choosing the alphabets simultaneously . If we had to choose two letters simultaneously ,then AB and BA would be the same case ,but here they are two separate cases(as we select A first in one and B in the other.)

Comment: Selection with replacement implies the selection is ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the question says with replacement rather than with repetition.  The words with replacement mean that we make a selection, return it to the set, then select again.  Therefore, the order of selection matters.  If we are making $k$ selections from a set with $n$ elements, we have $n$ choices for each of those $k$ selections, so by the Multiplication Principle, there are $n^k$ possible sequences of outcomes.  In this case, $n = 10$ and $k = r$, giving $10^r$ possible sequences of outcomes.

The formula $n^k$ represents the number of ways of selecting $k$ objects from $n$ objects when the order of selection matters and repetition is permitted.

The formula
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{n - 1} = \binom{n + k - 1}{k}$$
represents the number of ways of selecting $k$ objects from $n$ types of objects when repetition is permitted and the order of selection does not matter or the number of ways of placing $k$ indistinguishable objects in $n$ distinct boxes when each box has the capacity to hold all $k$ objects and some boxes may be left empty.